# diff 2 files by (class) method or function?

Tags: diff

This just occurred to me today. I've primarily been diffing files whole text using tools like BeyondCompare, etc.

Was wondering if there's a tool or functionality to do selective diffs of 2 files, where I only diff against one or set of specific (class) methods or functions or variables/properties within the given 2 files. Rather than a whole diff and then scroll through areas of interest.

Useful when you what to diff and merge 2 class libraries, etc. and only are concerned about methods/functions and members/properties (of interest) that have changed w/o having to diff the whole thing (and for diff whole thing, if diff tool not great, having to scroll and align changes as needed to view diffs when they're not matched up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a semantic diff/merge tool. There is a tool that allows you to get differences and merge up to method level (everything inside a method is treated like plain text). It's called semantic merge and you can find it here: http://semanticmerge.com.

*Disclaimer: I work on the Semantic Merge team in Codice Software.*